# Returning data using JSON & JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to pull the data I have within a JSON file onto my HTML page when a user interacts with the search field.

Here is a link to my JSON file: http://myjson.com/m0a3m

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search term">
<div id="matches" style="height:70px; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:pre"></div>
```

```js
$.getJSON( "https://api.myjson.com/bins/m0a3m", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  var dataArr = {};

  $.each( data, function( key, val, ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'><div class='c-name'>" + val.name + "</div><div class='c-address'>" + val.address.name + ', ' + val.address.line1 + ',' + val.address.town + ', ' + val.address.county + ', ' + val.address.postcode + "</div></li>" );
  });
  $( ".details").html("<ul>" + items + "</ul>");
});
```

Currently, all this does is display a few a lines of data. Could do with some real help linking it to the search bar.

Any suggestions or tips on what I should be read up on would be great!

Thanks

Comment: so, you want to filter the results based on what the user writes on the search field?

Comment: `$( ".details")` is targeting `class="details"`, which I don't see anywhere in your HTML. Can you provide a more complete example? Feel free to use https://jsfiddle.net/x742rn5a/ as a base.

Comment: Your logic could do with using `join()` on the array instead of relying on coercion to a string for the concatnation, but your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/x5vqg7t6/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `items` is an Array and `$.html` expects a string – you'll need to [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) your array of items to output a string.

```
$(".details").html("<ul>" + items.join('') + "</ul>");
```

> The join() method creates and returns a new string by concatenating
>   all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated
>   by commas or a specified separator string.

Answer (score 0):

You should join the array elements

```
$( ".details").html("<ul>" + items.join("") + "</ul>");
```